# Play Video Seamlessly in XNA

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna

I've wrote a code from [this source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904198.aspx) but when I want to loop the video, it will little bit freeze up for around half second. when I've searched in internet I've seen some guides in [Here](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/36568/682056.aspx#682056) such as make a thread and do everything in that. I also wrote a Thread for that but when I compile the project, It's the same. someone also said to me that your issue is you are using _videoThread.Join() . but when I remove that, the video plays so slow and I don't know why, this is my code, I would be grateful if someone help me :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.Threading;

namespace VideoTest2
{
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Thread _videoThread;
    Rectangle screen;

    Video _video;
    Video _video2;
    VideoPlayer _videoPlayer;
    Texture2D _videoTexture;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        _video = Content.Load<Video>("My Movie");
        _video2 = Content.Load<Video>("My Movie2");
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        _videoThread.Abort();
        _videoPlayer.Dispose();
    }


    private void DoVideoThread()
    {

        if (_videoPlayer == null)
        {
            _videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer();

            _videoPlayer.Play(_video);

        }

        if (_videoPlayer.State != MediaState.Stopped)
        {
            _videoTexture = _videoPlayer.GetTexture();
        }

        else //(_videoPlayer.State == MediaState.Stopped)
        {
            _videoPlayer.Play(_video);
        }
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

            _videoThread = new Thread(DoVideoThread) { IsBackground = true, Name = "VideoThread" };
            _videoThread.Start();
            _videoThread.Join();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // Drawing to the rectangle will stretch the  
        // video to fill the screen
        screen = new Rectangle(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.X,
            GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Y,
            GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,
            GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);

        // Draw the video, if we have a texture to draw.
        if (_videoTexture != null)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(_videoTexture, screen, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I notice your code is exactly the same as `Mahdi Khaleghi`'s on the XNA Create forums 4-February-2015 as indicated by your second link - _" I've seen some guides in [Here](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/36568/682056.aspx#682056)"_.  Even David Hunt pointed out _"I don't know about the little freeze, but **that code creates a new thread every frame**, which is definitely not something you want to be doing..."_ whoose advice you did not seem to take on board.

Answer (score 2):

> I also wrote a Thread for that but when I compile the project, It's the same. someone also said to me that your issue is you are using _videoThread.Join() . but when I remove that, the video plays so slow and I don't know why

When the `_videoThread.Join()` is present, it blocks the main thread (in this case the XNA game loop thread) until the thread exits.

> but when I remove that, the video plays so slow and I don't know why

That's because when you remove `_videoThread.Join()`

1. **A good thing** - main UI thread no longer waits for the child thread to complete and so *theoretically* your game should not freeze up
2. **bad thing** - because when you spawn the thread you do so during `Update()` without any check to see if the thread is running and instead **spawn a new thread each frame!**

To fix your immediate problems change this code:

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

            _videoThread = new Thread(DoVideoThread) { IsBackground = true, Name = "VideoThread" };
            _videoThread.Start();
            _videoThread.Join();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

...to:

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.Escape))
        {
            this.Exit();
        }

        if (_videoThread != null &&
            !_videoThread.IsAlive &&
            _videoPlayer.State == MediaState.Stopped)
        {
            _videoThread = new Thread(DoVideoThread) { IsBackground = true, Name = "VideoThread" };
            _videoThread.Start();
        }

       // Get the current video frame as a texture for this frame
       if (_videoPlayer.State != MediaState.Stopped)
       {
           _videoTexture = _videoPlayer.GetTexture();
       }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Now only one thread shall be spawned to play the video.

### Side Note

I'm not entirely convinced you need a thread just for media control, we don't do that with audio and it's not like you are responsible for decoding the video.

Comment: I replaced your code but when I compile it just show a blank screen :(

Comment: @NathanDrake Please see revised answer

Comment: I had that if statement on DoVideoThread() function, however, even if I delete my if statement to use that in the update method it says:  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0):

```
I modified it a bit, then its working fine, please do try like this below

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
        if (_videoThread == null &&
                       _videoPlayer.State == MediaState.Stopped)
        {
            _videoThread = new Thread(DoVideoThread) { IsBackground = true, Name = "VideoThread" };
            _videoThread.Start();
        }
}// modified draw
 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {         if (_videoThread != null &&    !_videoThread.IsAlive && _videoPlayer.State == MediaState.Stopped)
        {   _videoThread = new Thread(DoVideoThread) { IsBackground = true, Name = "VideoThread" };
            _videoThread.Start();}
        // Draw the video, if we have a texture to draw.
        if (_videoTexture != null)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(_videoTexture, screen, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
  }
}

Thanks
```